# Angular $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to show all lists and the tasks associated with each list. In my controller I have:

```
$http.get('api/list/').success(function (data) {
            $scope.lists = data;
            $scope.tasks = data[0].Task;
        });
```

This works for the first item but of course data[0].Task needs to be dynamic.  The problem I'm having is that this is being called once for each list.  I tried using a variable but it gets reset to it's original value.  I've also tried using a callback but no luck.  I'm not sure what I'm overlooking or if I'm going about it all wrong.

Comment: Is Lists->Tasks a one to many relationship?  This would mean that each task must have a list and can only have one list as its parent object.

Comment: Yes, it's a one to many relationship

Comment: Is `$scope.tasks` supposed to refer to all of the tasks, or only all of the tasks associated with the current (selected) list?  Also, you most likely shouldn't be calling `api/list/` multiple times.  If it's a one-to-many relationship you should be able to return a JSON array with each list having a Tasks property being a nested JSON array of the child tasks.  Then you can access those tasks with `$scope.lists.tasks`.

Comment: Still not having any luck with this.  If I add console.log('whatever') inside the $http.get, it shows once for every list, if I remove $scope.lists = data and $scope.tasks = data[0].Task console.log only gets called once, why is $http.get getting called once for each list?  I thought it was getting the data and filling my array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GET api/list/` request you probably return something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "List #1",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Task #1 on List #1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Task #2 on List #1"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Task #3 on List #1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "List #2",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Task #1 on List #2"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Task #2 on List #2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Task #3 on List #2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is assuming that you always want to return the associated tasks in an `api/list/` command.

You then only need to call this once every time you want to refresh all lists and all tasks.

You should have a single controller which is bound to a view, in which your $http.get is called.  It should set `$scope.lists = data` on success.

In your view you simply need two nested `ng-repeat` tags.  For example, you could use unordered lists:

```
<div ng-controller="ListsController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="list in lists">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="task in list.tasks">

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I haven't used angular but I'm pretty sure this is all you need to do.  A single AJAX call will populate a `<li>` element for each list, with nested `<li>` elements for each task belonging to that list.

Comment: I think I was causing myself problems trying to use a view within a page.  Finally got this to work:

<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="list in lists">
            {{list.Name}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="task in list.Task">
                    {{task.Name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to wrap the http.get in a factory and let it return `new` representations of your Lists that have the tasks in them. This way you get new references and it won't overwrite your existing objects. Essentially, you want the http.get to return new List objects in its success resolution.

After that, the controller gets the promise resolution, takes the new list object, and binds it into something thats on the scope. This will filter through to the rest of the page and let you preserve existing lists/tasks for the life of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If each list has a task and you want a list of them you can do this:

```
$scope.tasks = data.map(function(obj){return obj.task;})
```

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates an array based on what the function returns for each list.

Comment: that's returning each list, but 10 (the total number of lists) blank rows for each list instead of it's tasks